# System.timers.timer - unable to update label with time elapsed

Tags: multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I want to display time elapsed on Label control on  windows form.
for that i am using System.Timers.timer but unable to update Label with the elapsed time on button click event.

For example

```
Private Shared mtimer As System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub btnprocess_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnprocess.Click

'Counter to Calculate time as Process Starts
 mDate = Date.Now
 ''Create a timer with  second interval
 mtimer = New System.Timers.Timer()
 ''Hook the Elapsed event
 **AddHandler mtimer.Elapsed, AddressOf Processtick**
 mtimer.Start()
'set the interval 1 second 
 mtimer.Interval = 1000
 mtimer.Enabled = True

 ''Some functions 

   end sub 

Private Sub Processtick(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)

Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(mDate)
lblelapsed.Text = ts.Hours & ":" & ts.Minutes & ":" & ts.Seconds

End sub
```

tried above code but  it doesnt work, 
i want to update elapsed time on label control as soon as user click Process button
till  all the  functions get executed on button click.

Please help.

Comment: You are not allowed to update UI from a worker thread.  The kind that runs the Elapsed event handler.  Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.

Comment: thanks Hans tried with System.Windows.Forms.Timer but it shows time elapsed after the all functions get executed,as i want user can see time elapsed as soon as user clicks process button.

Comment: That's what happens when you do it the wrong way around.  Use a BackgroundWorker to perform long-running operations.  Use its ProgressChanged event to display progress.  Leave the UI thread with only the duty of updating UI.

Answer (score 0):

Since `System.Timers.Timer` runs on a separate thread it cannot directly update the GUI. You'll need to use `BeginInvoke` on the control to forward updates to the GUI thread. Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with vb.net, but you can find an example of how to do it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx